# Can you make the turtle the center of a circle in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making a tic tac toe game and when the user presses 'o' a circle is printed but the circle is always on the left of the turtle. i would like the turtle to be in the center of a box and draw the circle around itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add a minimal reproduceable example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I assum you know `radius` of this circle - so you can move `turtle` by `radius` in `x` or `y`, next draw circle, and next move it back by `radius` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to move turtle on your own - using `left`,`right`,`forward`, `penup`, `pendowm`.

---

Example

```
import turtle

radius = 100

# move
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(radius)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.pendown()

# circle
turtle.circle(radius)

# move back
turtle.penup()
turtle.right(-90)
turtle.forward(radius)
turtle.left(-90)
turtle.pendown()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to draw a circle centered around a Python turtle without moving the turtle.  The first is the `dot()` method.  It takes a *diameter*, rather than a *radius*, and optionally allows you to specify the color at the same time:

```
import turtle

RADIUS = 100

turtle.dot(RADIUS * 2)
turtle.dot(RADIUS * 1.6, turtle.bgcolor())  # "unfill" the circle

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Another way to do it is via *stamping*, that is, make the turtle cursor itself a circle, size it, and then call `stamp()`:

```
import turtle

RADIUS = 100
CURSOR_RADIUS = 10

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.fillcolor(turtle.bgcolor())
turtle.shapesize(RADIUS / CURSOR_RADIUS, outline=RADIUS/5)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Both of the above have the side effect of overwritting anything that the circle surrounds, which doesn't seem like a problem for tic-tac-toe.  To avoid this, you can, of course, temporarily shift the turtle's position, as @furas suggests:

```
import turtle

RADIUS = 100

turtle.width(RADIUS/5)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - RADIUS)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.circle(RADIUS)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + RADIUS)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.done()
```

[image]